# Intuitive explanation of neutral / normal form in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, term-rewriting

It is possible to distinguish Normal terms which don't contain beta redex as a sub-expression, from others like so

```
data WithBound a = Var | Other a

data Normal a
  = Neutral (Neutral a)
  | Abstract (Normal (WithBound a))

data Neutral a
  = Variable a
  | Apply (Neutral a) (Normal a)
```

Is there any intuitive explanation as to why this property would hold ?
It might be entirely self-evident somehow after you look at it long enough but it does not prompt straight out to me as of now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can reassure you that this property is not immediately self-evident. In trying to describe/enumerate the set of normal forms, the main observation required is the following:

- Abstraction preserves normal forms: if $t$ is normal, than so is $\lambda x.t$.
- Application does **not** preserve normal forms: if $t$ and $u$ are normal, $t\ u$ may contain a redex!

We want to characterize the normal forms **for which we can not create redexes when performing applications**. Obviously, this occurs iff $t$ is a $\lambda$-abstraction. In particular, we can take $u$ to be anything we want, so long as it is in normal form.

For $t$, we need either a variable or an application, itself already in normal form. This allows a convenient recursive definition for $t$, which we will call *neutral*:
$$t=x$$
or
$$t=t_1\ t_2$$
with $t_2$ any normal form, and $t_1\ t_2$ also in normal form, i.e. $t_1$ also a neutral term.

But this is exactly your definition of `Neutral`!

One can carry out this process further to characterize exactly the normalizing (resp. strongly normalizing) terms, if we furthermore allow *weak head expansions*.